# Coordinates in Java from file

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to read some coordinates in from a file and get their `x` and `y` values as integers so that I can work out the distance between two points. I've managed to use `Scanner` to grab some numbers from each line, but the method now seems to be reading each digit as a separate number. So when I get use sample data of:

```
(25, 4) (1, -6)
```

I end up getting:

```
(2, 5) (4, 1)
```

The code I'm using to get the numbers from file and to output the answer is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        sc.useDelimiter("\\D*");
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            double xOne = sc.nextInt();
            double yOne = sc.nextInt();
            double xTwo = sc.nextInt();
            double yTwo = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(xOne + "," + yOne + "," + xTwo + "," + yTwo);
            int d = (int)Math.sqrt(Math.pow((xTwo - xOne), 2) + Math.pow((yTwo - yOne), 2));
            System.out.println(d);
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the input file formatted? That could be the issue.

Comment: Each set of coordinates in the format of (x, y) (x, y) is a new line

Comment: Are the parentheses and commas in the file?

Comment: The parentheses and commas are in the file, along with the '-' to tell me if the numbers are negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression `\D*` matches any sequence of non-digits, including an empty one.  Because it matches the empty string, your scanner is going to read one character at a time.

Write

```
sc.useDelimiter("\\D+");
```

instead.

Comment: That works with getting the full numbers working but I then lose the "-", so I can't tell which numbers are negative

Comment: Right, so maybe you want an expression like "[(),\\s]+"